# Proving that interpolation polynomial has to be an odd function

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, interpolation

Let's consider $(n + 1) -$evenly distributed nodes on interval $[-1, 1]$ and we want to interpolation odd function $f$. I want to prove, that interpolation polynomial:

$$L_nf(x) = \sum_{j = 0}^n f(a_j)\prod_{k = 0, k \ne j}^n \frac{x - a_k}{a_j - a_k}$$

has to be an odd function.

**My work so far**

Let's firstly notice, that nodes $a_i$ can be written in a form of $a_i = \frac{2i}{n} - 1$. We want to prove that $L_nf(-x) = -L_nf(x)$. Let's rewrite left equality:

$$L_nf(-x) = \sum_{j = 0}^n f(a_j) \prod_{k = 0, k \ne j}^n \frac{-x-a_k}{a_j - a_k}=$$

$$= \sum_{j = 0}^n f(a_j)\prod_{k = 0, k \ne j}^n\frac{-x-\frac{2k}{n} + 1}{\frac{2j}{n} - 1 - \frac{2k}{n} + 1}= \sum_{j = 0}^n f(a_j) \prod_{k = 0, k \ne j}^n \frac{-xn - 2k + n}{2(j - k)} = $$
$$(-1)^n \sum_{j = 0}^n f(a_j) \prod_{k = 0, k \ne j}^n \frac{xn + 2k - n}{2(j - k)}$$

whereas,

$$-L_nf(x) = (-1)\sum_{j = 0}^n f(a_j) \prod_{k = 0, k \ne j}^n \frac{x - 2k + n}{2(j - k)}$$

And here - I'm not sure how to prove the equality of those two expressions. Also - somehow we have to use fact, that function $f$ is odd, but I don't see room for it. Could you please help me with this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This claim relies on the fact that the minimal degree interpolation polynomial $p$, as obtained using the Lagrange interpolation formula, is unique for the given function table.

As $f(x)=-f(-x)$, the same $p$ also interpolates $-f(-x)$. Reversing the operations, here the symmetry of the sampling nodes sequence is used, this means that also $-p(-x)$ interpolates $f$. Due to the uniqueness this implies $p(x)=-p(-x)$.

Comment: Since $p(x)$ interpolates $-f(-x)$, then $-p(x)$ has to interpolate $f(-x)$. And now, since our nodes are symmetric, we can say that $-p(-x)$ interpolates $f(x)$. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes. The important part is that all interpolation is for the same node set. Thus it just needs to be symmetric, the construction via the equidistant sequence is one way to ensure this.